# Uso correcto de las comas en la siguiente oración

Tags: gramática, puntuación

Mi primer intento fue el siguiente:

> Gracias también a los escritores Pepe y Manuel de quienes, Juanito, se
>   llevó de cada uno un libro firmado.

Dudé si poner "de cada uno" entre comas también.
O tal vez poner solo "de quienes" entre comas.

Ahora me inclino por esta versión:

> Gracias también a los escritores Pepe y Manuel, de quienes Juanito se
>   llevó de cada uno un libro firmado.

¿Cuál de las dos opciones es la forma correcta? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Yo no usaría ninguna coma en esa frase.

Comment: La segunda frase quedó mejor que la primera, pero también es posible otra version, sin coma; las comas son muchas veces cuestión de estilo; la frase me parece bastante rara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice [la *Ortografía*](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UnItLcixdVUYzWgz) de la RAE:

> Dada la diversidad de contextos en los que aparece [la coma] y la variedad de usos que presenta, no es extraño que sea también el signo de puntuación que más dudas plantea.

Dicho esto, a mí la segunda opción que planteas me parece suficiente. Sin embargo, y dado que la frase parece sacada de un ejercicio, se podría discutir el uso de más comas en la oración. Las pongo entre paréntesis:

> Gracias(,) también(,) a los escritores(,) Pepe y Manuel, de quienes Juanito se llevó(,) de cada uno(,) un libro firmado.

Estas comas entre paréntesis se podrían debatir. En principio, la coma se ha vinculado tradicionalmente a la presencia de una pausa breve o débil en el discurso, aunque esta relación hay veces que no se verifica. Si yo leo la frase del ejemplo, la única coma que parece clara es la que has colocado en el segundo ejemplo, que delimita una oración subordinada y coincide con una pausa en el diálogo. Pero comento las demás:

- Se podría poner *también* entre comas si esta palabra forma parte de un inciso en el diálogo, si quieres remarcar que estás procediendo a continuar con unos agradecimientos iniciados anteriormente.
- Los nombres *Pepe y Manuel* podrían ser una aposición explicativa con respecto al sustantivo *escritores*, por lo que tendrían que ir entre comas.
- La expresión *de cada uno* podría ir como un inciso, entre comas, para recalcar su significado.

Entiendo, en todo caso, que estas comas son opcionales porque su presencia o ausencia no altera el significado de la frase. Y además, como dice la *Ortografía*:

> Se registran, así, estilos de escritura más o menos trabados en función de que se elija poner un menor o un mayor número de las llamadas comas opcionales [...]. Sin que pueda hablarse en estos casos de puntuación correcta o incorrecta, como regla general debe optarse por un empleo racional y equilibrado de la coma, evitando su uso tanto por exceso como por defecto, pues en ambas circunstancias se entorpece la legibilidad del texto.

Comment: Yo no usaría ninguna coma en esa frase. No hay posibilidad alguna de el uso o no de una coma cambie el significado por lo tanto para mi todas son innecesarias.